# Bootstrap Card - Align two buttons in card footer

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap Card, and in the footer, I have two buttons. What I need to do is align one button in the absolute center and another smaller button on the left side of the footer. And both buttons should be vertically middle aligned.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Header</div>
    <div class="card-body">Content</div> 
    <div class="card-footer">      
      <div class="btn-wrapper text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary text-dark btn-sm">Remove</a> 
        <a class="btn btn-warning" style="">Next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This aligns both cards to the center. But I need the Next button in center while the Remove button to the left. How do I do that?

Here is the jsbin for it: https://jsbin.com/vesobayuci/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the updated [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/sikagebetu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
.remove-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I liked this solution. But when I hover over the button, it moves too much to the bottom. Can that be resolved?

Comment: @asanas It's working fine. I didn't find such issues

Comment: @asanas, theres no such issue like that. Can you confirm if you have updated any code

Answer (score 2):

Please check Demo
https://output.jsbin.com/cezegetufe

```css
.btn-wrapper .btn-secondary {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Card Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Card Header and Footer</h2>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Header</div>
      <div class="card-body">Content</div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="btn-wrapper text-center d-flex justify-content-between">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary  btn-sm text-white d-flex align-items-center">Remove</a>
          <a class="btn btn-warning" style="">Next</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely position them like so

```css
.card-footer .btn-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.card-footer .btn-wrapper .btn{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.card-footer .btn-wrapper .btn-warning{
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card-footer .btn-wrapper .btn-secondary{
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <h2>Card Header and Footer</h2>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Header</div>
    <div class="card-body">Content</div> 
    <div class="card-footer">      
      <div class="btn-wrapper text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary pull-left text-dark btn-sm">Remove</a> 
        <a class="btn btn-warning" style="">Next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `transform` property and Bootstrap 4 classes

```css
.btn-warning {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Card Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Card Header and Footer</h2>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">Header</div>
      <div class="card-body">Content</div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="btn-wrapper position-relative">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary text-dark btn-sm">Remove</a>
          <a class="btn btn-warning position-absolute">Next</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```